# Signing a jar causing issue

Tags: java, applet, signed-applet

i have following code in applet that basically writes some data to a file being passed as parameter to writeFile method()

```
public class appletToWrite extends Applet{
public int writeFile(String asPath, String asData, int aiOverwrite)
{
    int j = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,asPath+ "testing gng on", "data mil gaya!!!", 0);
    try {
        File localFile = new File(asPath);
        if (localFile.exists()) {
            if(aiOverwrite==1){
                localFile.delete();
                j =JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"overwrite = 1", "data mil gaya!!!", 0);
            }
            else{
                j = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "overwrite = 0", "data mil gaya!!!", 0);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        j = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "niche aa gaye", "data mil gaya!!!", 0);
        localFile.createNewFile();
        BufferedWriter localBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(localFile, true));
        String str1;
        localBufferedWriter.write(asData);
        localBufferedWriter.close();
        return 1;
    }
    catch (Exception localException) {
        j = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "catch mein aa gaya "+localException.getMessage(), "data nahi gaya!!!", 0);
        localException.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

i have self signed the jar using following commands

```
javac appletToWrite.java
jar cvf AppletClass.jar *.class
keytool -genkey -validity 3650 -keystore pKeyStore -alias formBuilder
keytool -selfcert -keystore pKeyStore -alias formBuilder -validity 3650
jarsigner -keystore pKeyStore AppletClass.jar formBuilder
```

but still its not getting all the permission to write the file on local machine am getting file permission denied any idea why?

Comment: can you post the stack trace of your exception

Comment: this is done on local machine and without any server so no stack trace it just say permission denied for file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the replies 
got answer myslef actually thing was permissions are allowed with in applet only a call from outside world is not letting me get the permissions. I was making a call from javascript and was hoping to get permissions as well

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be signed applet is NOT allowed to access everything. Depends on your browser JRE setting. The default setting is defined within the JRE (search for a property file in your JRE folder - one of these defines it). But browsers can override that.

Try to create the file in the users home folder.

Comment: i did the same thing before signing an applet and accessing the local resources for read/write but somehow this time its creating mess.. couldnt get where i am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

If both the following are true - I would suggest an entirely different approach.

- The [File
  Service **(sandboxed)** demo](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs)
  works for your use-case.
- The user
  can be expected to be running Java
  1.6.0_10+ (new generation plug-in).

The linked demo. (written by me) is sand-boxed, and only when the user goes to open a file does the JRE ask them if they want to give it permission.

*It is not necessary for sand-boxed code to be digitally signed.*

Since the new generation plug-in, the JNLP API used in the demo. can be accessed by applets that are embedded in a web page.  An example of that can be seen in the [GIFanim applet](http://pscode.org/gifanim/#applet).

Comment: the sandboxed example is working fine on my system.. can you please tell me how to sign my applet now?